# Generate regular point grid in a polygon layer in QGIS or PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Is it possible to merge two functionalities in QGIS, I mean the tools "random points inside polygons" and "regular points", both in vector > research tool, to select regular grid points inside polygons?

Either a python code is well accepted. Generally I use to create a vector regular point net then I select only the points inside the vector polygons. Regular points creation can be demanding for wide areas and I would like to do everything in one step.

Comment: You could create a usual point grid, clip it to the polygons and then randomly select points from the clipped layer. Would this suit your needs?

Comment: Hi, I would like to avoid to create points on a large extension because is very time consuming, I would like to create it directly in the polygons

Comment: How is this very time consuming? Set the extent to the polygon layer, define spacing, and you're done.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue, because if your polygon has an extent of 100 * 100 km and you have to create a point net of 10 m space, it takes too much and I think is not the correct way to go on

Comment: Yeah, but you hadn't mentioned these prerequisites before and that you already discarded this possible solution. Maybe you could expand your post, mentioning any other prerequisites which might be relevant.